# SQL select DISTINCT with Order BY and Group BY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello guys I need some help with a query.
With this `select` query from bellow I received the results from the left table.(see attached image).
The problem is that I need to modify this query for having results like in the right table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM(
SELECT 
TO_CHAR(D1111MOI__.D1111TFROM + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS TFROM,
TO_CHAR(D1111MOI__.D1111TTILL + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS TTILL,
D1110MOL__.D1110ORDER AS NR,
R0507UNIT_.R0507NAME_ AS NAME,
D1110MOL__.D1110POW__ AS AV

FROM D1110MOL__
INNER JOIN D1109MOH__
ON D1110MOL__.D1109ID___ = D1109MOH__.D1109ID___
AND D1110MOL__.D1110DDAYS = D1109MOH__.D1109DDAYS
INNER JOIN D1111MOI__
ON D1109MOH__.D1109ID___ = D1111MOI__.D1109ID___
AND D1109MOH__.D1109DDAYS = D1111MOI__.D1111DDAYS
INNER JOIN R0507UNIT_
ON D1110MOL__.R0507ID___ = R0507UNIT_.R0507ID___

WHERE (D1111MOI__.D1111TFROM >= TO_DATE('17.05.2017 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
AND (D1111MOI__.D1111TTILL  <= TO_DATE('18.05.2017 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')))
AND D1109MOH__.D1109TYPE_ = 1
AND D1110MOL__.D1110SEL__ = 1
)
ORDER BY TFROM,NR;
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` and `SUM()`

Comment: @jarlh what is the problem?

Comment: Make it easy to help you. Create a minimal example. Have sample data and the expected result as formatted text.

Comment: @jarlh I attached all of this, or you can't see it?

Comment: I don't see any definitions or sample data for `D1110MOL__`, `D1109MOH__`, `D1111MOI__` etc, just a query and a screenshots of actual vs expected results. Perhaps a simpler example would illustrate the issue without the 4-way join and date manipulation.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I don't think the name of the table is relevant... Only I need is to modify this query to generates the right table  from the image not the left one. I need to make a sum(AV) but it's not working..

Comment: But the point is I can't test your query to fix it, because I don't have your tables.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You don't need to test it because it's working, The sample data you can consider the left table...I don't need the exact query, just some guidance

Comment: @BOB A bit late, but for future reference; The point is not to test *your* code, but we want to be able to test *our adaptations* to your code. An answer with bugs or a wrong result helps nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
SELECT TFROM, TTILL, SUM(AV) as TOTAL_AV
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR (D1111MOI__.D1111TFROM + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS TFROM,
             TO_CHAR (D1111MOI__.D1111TTILL + INTERVAL '3' HOUR, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') AS TTILL,
             D1110MOL__.D1110ORDER AS NR,
             D1110MOL__.D1110POW__ AS AV
        FROM D1110MOL__
             INNER JOIN D1109MOH__ ON D1110MOL__.D1109ID___ = D1109MOH__.D1109ID___ AND D1110MOL__.D1110DDAYS = D1109MOH__.D1109DDAYS
             INNER JOIN D1111MOI__ ON D1109MOH__.D1109ID___ = D1111MOI__.D1109ID___ AND D1109MOH__.D1109DDAYS = D1111MOI__.D1111DDAYS
             INNER JOIN R0507UNIT_ ON D1110MOL__.R0507ID___ = R0507UNIT_.R0507ID___
       WHERE     (    D1111MOI__.D1111TFROM >= TO_DATE ('17.05.2017 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
                  AND (D1111MOI__.D1111TTILL <= TO_DATE ('18.05.2017 21:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')))
             AND D1109MOH__.D1109TYPE_ = 1
             AND D1110MOL__.D1110SEL__ = 1)
 GROUP BY TFROM, TTILL
 ORDER BY TFROM;
```

Comment: I tried but I have `not a group by expression` error

Comment: @BOB try no. I removed ordering by NR, it caused the error because it wasn't in GROUP BY (and it should not be)

Comment: Thank you man,  I made the same mistake and I didn't understand why I'm having this error

Comment: No problem @BOB I'm glad I helped